# How to prove $\sup (|f(x)+g(x)|) \le \sup |f(x)| + \sup |g(x)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I can prove $\sup (|f(x)+g(x)|) \le \sup |f(x)| + \sup |g(x)|$ and $\inf (|f(x)+g(x)|) \ge \inf |f(x)| + \inf |g(x)|$. I feel I need to use them somehow together with triangle inequality, but I can not figure out how exactly.

I already proved this by cases by simply opening absolute values from both sides of inequality, but that proof was very tedious and does not look concise.

Comment: Your question is something, your body is another.

Comment: My question is in the title, in the body I wrote just my thoughts as to possible ways to solve it and other facts I may have to use. So the question is how to prove $\sup (|f(x)+g(x)|) \le \sup |f(x)| + \sup |g(x)|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One has

$$|f(x)+g(x)|\le |f(x)|+|g(x)|\le \sup{|f(x)|}+\sup{|g(x)|}$$

The first inequality is the triangle inequality and the second is the fact that a supremum is an upper bound

By definition the supremum is the least upper bound and so

$$\sup{|f(x)+g(x)|}\le \sup{|f(x)|}+\sup{|g(x)|}$$

The proof for $\inf$ follows the same pattern